# FileNotFound exception thrown for logback config after upgrade to spring 4.2

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, upgrade, logback

Since I upgraded from spring-boot-starter-parent 1.2.3-RELEASE to 1.3.4-RELEASE and spring.version 4.1.6 to 4.2.5, my project has been throwing the following exception:

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'config/logback.xml'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents\workspace\application\config\logback.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

The exception is thrown after it has initialized the logback configuration that is in my resources folder located in  C:\Documents\workspace\application\src\main\config\logback.xml first.

I'm upgrading because my mongodb databases now require authentication using SCRAM-SHA-1 mechanism which 1.2.3 was unable to provide. 1.3.4 seems to be the smallest version of spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb with that authMechanism.

I tried upgrading to spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.X and I wasn't getting the FileNotFoundException after the logback initialization, but my application wasn't starting.

I even tried changing the value of my logging.config property in my application.properties file but I got a different error.

Has anyone experienced this, and do you have any suggestions about how I can get past this, and have my application start?

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.workspace</groupId>
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.0.21</tomcat.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fakemongo</groupId>
            <artifactId>fongo</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <!--<version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <!--<version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <!--<version>${spring-boot.version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <!--<version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
            <artifactId>javamelody-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.56.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/assembly</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/config</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jks</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jceks</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.build.finalName}.${BUILD_NUMBER}</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

and the logging property in application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://application:application@mongo_cluster1.com,mongo_cluster_2.com,mongo_cluster3.com/application?replicaSet=uat-RepSet&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1
database.name=application
logging.config=config/logback.xml
```

Here is the Logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <property resource="application.properties" />

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %5p | %t | %-55logger{55} | %m %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="application" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashSocketAppender">
        <host>port</host>
        <!-- port is optional (default value shown) -->
        <port>port</port>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logs/${pom.name}.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %5p | %t | %-55logger{55} | %m %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/${pom.name}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>13</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <!--<appender name="LOGSTASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashSocketAppender">
        <host>host</host>
        <port>port</port>
    </appender>-->

    <logger name="Logger" additivity="false" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="application"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.application.techquest.service.trace.logger.MethodBodyLogger" additivity="false" level="OFF">
        <appender-ref  ref="application"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="application"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Here is the console log

```
19:53:42,800 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/Documents/workspace/application/target/classes/logback.xml]
19:53:42,908 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
19:53:42,922 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Will scan for changes in [file:/C:Documents/workspace/application/target/classes/logback.xml] 
19:53:42,922 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeTask scanning period to 30 seconds
19:53:42,944 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
19:53:42,949 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
19:53:42,960 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
19:53:43,055 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashSocketAppender]
19:53:43,307 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [application]
19:53:43,309 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@16:18 - no applicable action for [encoder], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder]]
19:53:43,309 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@17:22 - no applicable action for [pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder][pattern]]
19:53:43,313 |-INFO in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashSocketAppender[application] - Defaulting maxMessageSize to [65000]
19:53:43,328 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
19:53:43,330 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
19:53:43,332 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
19:53:43,340 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@3439f68d - Will use zip compression
19:53:43,348 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Active log file name: logs/pom.name_IS_UNDEFINED.log
19:53:43,348 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [logs/pom.name_IS_UNDEFINED.log]
19:53:43,351 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [iswLogger] to INFO
19:53:43,351 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [iswLogger] to false
19:53:43,351 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [application] to Logger[iswLogger]
19:53:43,352 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[iswLogger]
19:53:43,352 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[iswLogger]
19:53:43,352 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework] to INFO
19:53:43,352 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[org.springframework]
19:53:43,352 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.workspace.techquest.service.trace.logger.MethodBodyLogger] to OFF
19:53:43,352 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [com.workspace.techquest.service.trace.logger.MethodBodyLogger] to false
19:53:43,352 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [application] to Logger[com.workspace.techquest.service.trace.logger.MethodBodyLogger]
19:53:43,352 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - ROOT level set to INFO
19:53:43,352 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
19:53:43,352 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
19:53:43,352 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [application] to Logger[ROOT]
19:53:43,352 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
19:53:43,354 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@dbd940d - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'config/logback.xml'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents\workspace\application\config\logback.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:255)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:224)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.workspace.Application.main(Application.java:14)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents\workspace\application\config\logback.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:289)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:255)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:224)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.workspace.Application.main(Application.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents\workspace\application\config\logback.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:281)
    ... 14 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I try changing my logging.config property to src\main\config\logback.xml, the exception changes to

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'src/main/config/logback.xml'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@16:18 - no applicable action for [encoder], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@17:22 - no applicable action for [pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder][pattern]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@16:18 - no applicable action for [encoder], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@17:22 - no applicable action for [pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder][pattern]]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:255)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:224)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.workspace.Application.main(Application.java:14)
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your application.properties file?

Comment: Have you tried logging.config=classpath:logback.xml?

Comment: yes. same exception.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [/logback.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Answer (score 2):

I think this is mainly caused because you filter out the logback.xml in your pom. Either:

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/config</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
</resource>
```

or:

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/config</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
            <include>logback.xml</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
```

both should solve your issue.

Comment: I get this exception when I set filtering to false: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [/logback.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Comment: and this exception when I include the logback: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@16:18 - no applicable action for [encoder], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@17:22 - no applicable action for [pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder][pattern]]

Comment: but, you do have a logback.xml in your src/main/config folder, right?

Comment: Yes, I do. In the logs shared, the app is configuring the logback that’s part of the compiled target just fine. But even when it can recognize the config/logback.xml file, it throws errors that it cannot configure it properly. That really confuses me

Comment: Based on the logs provided above, your logback.xml does not get recognize. When using Spring Boot, a default configuration for Logback is provided which is overridden when you add your own logback.xml. - this can be seen in first log, default applied, but override is not found. It is also strange that the path you mention  you have your logback differs from the path in the log message: 
C:\Documents\workspace\application\config\logback.xml
vs.
C:\Documents\workspace\application\src\main\config\logback.xml
Have you tried to put the logback.xml the folder spring is looking?

Comment: yes. when I try that, I get the "..configuration error detected...no applicable action for encoder..." error message similar to the second console output shows

Comment: ok, I think your logback.xml is not ok. Can you post that, too?

Comment: updated. but again, my logback gets instantiated/configured first and then spring tries to reconfigure it, for lack of a better term, and that's when these errors are occurring